# how to show first 50 words of a text field in django template

Tags: python, django

I have a field like this in my Django template:

```
<p>{{news.description}}<p>
```

I wanna show the first 50 words of this field. How can I do it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatewords):

```
{{ news.description|truncatewords:50 }}
```

Comment: If you don't want the ellipsis, you can add ```|slice:":-4"``` to remove it and the space, or ```:-3``` if you want to keep the space.